# Run jUnit tests per elements in a list

Tags: java, junit

**I have a large number of tests as described below:**
The expected value (y_position_expected) is hard coded to the jUnit tests. The tests send a value (x_position) to a method which does some statistics and returns the results (y_position_actual). This result is the actual value which is compared to the expected value.

```
public class PositionNormalizerTest {

    public Normalizers norman ;


    @Before
    public void beforeFunction() {
        norman = DislocationUtils.getPositionService().getNormalizers() ;

    }

    @Test
    public void testAmountForNumberString1() {
        String y_position_expected = 100.0d ;
        double x_position = <A DOUBLE GOES HERE> ;
        double y_position_actual = norman.normalizeYPosition(x_position).getAmount() ;
        assertEquals(y_position_expected, y_position_actual, 0.001) ;
    }
}
```

The value of x_position comes from the values of a map which is much larger but similar to what is depicted below:

```
checkpoints = {"alpha":[0.0d, 10.0d,200.0d], "beta":[50.0d, 44.0d,12.0d]}
```

The keys of this map are strings and the values are lists of doubles. Accordingly, the test has to run for every single element in every single value.

**Problem:**
Given the size of the map (checkpoints) and the number of tests, it takes a very long time to create all the tests manually. Therefore, I am looking for a way to make a single jUnit test class with multiple test cases iterate over the values of the map automatically and run the tests. I tried normal loop but as soon as the assertion comes to a conclusion, may it be a fail or a pass the test case ends without continuing the loop. Is there a way to do this? Can I do it using annotation? Thanks.

Comment: Use testng and @DataProvider (if I recall correctly) or just loop over data and catch assertion failures yourself to delay the handling.

Comment: So I posted the answer myself twice so far but the moderators deleted both and I can't undelete them. They don't seem to get that theories are the best way of doing this.
Unfortunately, the structure of my test does not allow parametrized tests and using testng is too much of a change for the main body of the code is very mature by now. Accordingly, the answer I could come up with was to use theories and datapoints. There are lots of good tutorials for it on the web which the moderators who delete the answer may learn something from.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameterized test:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PositionNormalizerTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        //here you create and return the collection of your values
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{{"alpha", 0.0d, 10.0d, 200.0d}, {"beta", 50.0d, 44.0d,12.0d}});
    }

    @Parameter 
    public String key; //alpha

    @Parameter(1)
    public double d1; //0.0d

    @Parameter(2)
    public double d2; //10.0d

    @Parameter(3)
    public double d3; //200.0d

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //here's your test
        //this method will be executed for every element from the data list
    }
}
```

You can get more info about parameterized tests here: [Parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests)